# How to send variable to another php page?

Tags: php

**test.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="testout.php">
irum1 : <input type="text" name="irum1" size="20" value="">
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**testout.php**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>testout</title>
</head>
<body>
  getting irum1 = <?=$irum1?>
</body>
</html>
```

**result (when I input "Hello php")**

```
getting irum1 =
```

**it should be**

```
getting irum1 = Hello php
```

Above codes are about sending parameter that user input to another page. but the code is not working. I couldn't see the parameter. I'm on doing this work by apm (apache+php+mysql). What is the problem? I'm newbie on php.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the value correctly to the page , but you are not retrieving it on the other page.

On your `testout.php` do this change..

```
<html>
<head>
<title>testout</title>
</head>
<body>
  getting irum1 = <?php echo isset($_POST['irum1']) ? $_POST['irum1'] : "Value not passed";?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working well. But I typed correctly compare to my php book. Can you explain to me what's the difference your code and my code?

Answer (score 2):

When you submit a form, you're sending an array of data via the method defined by the form.   In this case POST.

You have to grab 'irum1' form data out of the POST array before you can use it.

On testout.php

```
<?php $irum1 = $_POST['irum1'] ?>

<html>
<head>
<title>testout</title>
</head>
<body>
  getting irum1 =  <font color="blue"><?=$irum1?></font>
</body>
</html>
```